# How do I beat the Kayran?

Tags: the-witcher-2

How to beat the Kayran, with Xbox controller on PC?
I cut off four arms and the Kayran is down to 1/4 health. I get swept on one tentacle, I am clicking as fast as possible (blue X), yet even when the yellow
bar appears to be full I still get thrown off the tentacle.

Answer (score 1):

After the sequence on the tentacle you are thrown off. That's normal. The Kayran should now have compeletely destroyed the bridge and big chunk landed right on it.

Look for the bridge chunk and walk up the slope, this triggers a QTE, which is the final stage of the boss.